# Is it possible for a browser plug-in/toolbar to identify the current URL of an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, iframe, plugins, toolbar

My site frames content like DiggBar and the Facebook share bar.

If a user wants to break out of the framed content, and visit the underlying site directly, we cannot guarantee the current page will be displayed, since there is no way for JS or HTML to query the current URL of an iFrame (for security reasons).

All we can do is show the page originally loaded in the iFrame.

The question: if we set up the service as a toolbar or plug-in, could we then have the capability to query a given web page and ascertain the current URL for each iFrame?  This way, if a user clicks to different pages in the iFrame, then decides to break out, we can guarantee displaying the correct page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you decide to step out of the JS/DHTML boundaries, you get more power and capabilities. 
There should be a way to do so in each browser you decide to support (IE, FF, etc.). Though there would be the price one might pay for requiring a software installation.